How to get response from service worker with header 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'?
I am getting the font in uint8Array format in service worker.
I will create a header
    options.headers = new Headers({
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
                    'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes',
                    'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=0',
                    'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 23 May 2024 00:29:23 GMT',
                    'Content-Type': 'font/ttf',
                    'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding',
                    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip',
                    'Date': 'Thu, 23 May 2024 21:48:17 GMT',
                    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                    'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=5',
                    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
                    });

And send new Response from Service Worker
 event.respondWith((async () => {
   const file = await readFile(path);
   if(destination === 'font') {
      const stream = new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
          controller.enqueue(file)
          controller.close()
        }
      })
     
      return new Response(stream, options)
  }
}) ());

But it is not work.
What am I doing wrong here?
On the Internet I found only the version that I wrote. I guess I just don’t know what to look for or watch.

It doesn't look like you're actually sending chunked transfer encoding. Just setting the header.

Is it possible to see an example somewhere?
